# Using xlUp to count rows in a named Column

Tags: vba, excel

It is very easy to know the last row in which a cell has a value by using

```
f_liens.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
```

However, when using the assigned column names instead of the letters, I get a error. Here is what I want to do, but I get errors:

```
 f_liens.Cells(Rows.Count, "col_pc").End(xlUp).row
```

I am pretty sure, once I know how to make it work, i will then be able to use

```
f_liens.Cells(Rows.Count, "col_" & strtype ).End(xlUp).row
```

Where strType will depend on previous code.

Does anyone know how to refer to the last entry in a named column? If not this way, I'll accept any other working way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f_liens.Cells(Rows.Count, Range("col_pc").Column).End(xlUp).row
```